# Syntax of textarea in out.println()

Tags: jsp, textarea

I am a beginner in JSP.

I want to show textarea on some condition.

```
<%if(select!=null)
     out.println("<textarea name='test' id='test'><%=select%></textarea>");
%>
```

It is showing syntax error on line 2.

Error name::String literal is not properly closed by a double quote.

Please help..

**EDIT**  select is a array of strings i.e `String select[]`

Answer (score 0):

I see you are conflating of how to use a servlet and a JSP.

It is important to notice that the usage of HTML is no the same for JSP as Servlet.

Although it might be true that you need to print out html code in a servlet,

```
 out.println("<textarea name='test' id='test'><%=select%></textarea>");
```

This does not hold in a JSP

To remove the error from your code, simply omit the "out.printl()" part and write instead the following:
Also don't forget the closing/opening paranthesis!
Copy + paste snippet below.

```
  <%if(select!= null){ %>
        <textarea name='test' id='test'><%=select%></textarea>
   <%} %>
```